# how to write a program to validate another program/script?

Tags: python, ruby, testing, validation

How to write a program to test another program/script?

I need to test a ruby script that is an echo server; how should I write a program to validate the correct working of the echo server script ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking : you need a client that connects to the echo server, prints something, reads something, compares what was written to what was read.

Comment: yes i got that echo server working, and tested that manually with telnet, thing is i need to automate the test process to validate that the echo server displays what the telnet client sends, so this need to be written as a script/prog in an other language or ruby itself.

Comment: In Python there is a `telnet` library, and I presume Ruby as one too. If you are able to test using telnet it should be straightforward to use the library to automate that.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) and [dejaGnu](http://www.gnu.org/software/dejagnu/).

Answer (score 1):

You could start with something like this for a TCP echo server:

```
require "socket"

hostname = "localhost"
port = 2000

s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)

s.print "something\n"     # was "something"

line = s.gets
line.chop!

if line == "something"
    puts "echo test  passed"
else
    puts "echo test failed: rcvd [#{line}]\n"
end

s.close
```

Depending of what kind of testing you need, you can grow the test client, use several sockets, multiple threads, a test framework such as Test::Unit, Cucumber ...

---

EDIT: it works with the following echo server, I just had to add a '\n' to the client data

```
require 'socket'  

port = 2000

server = TCPServer.open(port)
loop {                         
  client = server.accept
  data = client.gets 
  client.puts data
  client.close
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, this doesnot work, i tried this client for my echo server.

But the concept was the desired one.

Comment: Well, it works with the server above, I just had to add a `\n` to the exchanged string.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a built-in unit testing framework called [Test::Unit](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/classes/Test/Unit.html).  However, I tend to prefer working with the [Rspec](http://rspec.info/) BDD framework.  Ideally, BDDers like to write the tests before the actual code, but you can certainly write tests after the fact.